# contentWindow vs contentDocument in iframess

Tags: iframe, drupal, cypress

I am working on a project where I am creating automated tests for a Drupal based tool.

I used the solution provided on the Cypress forums here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress

One funny thing I observed is that there are two types of iframes being used on the frontend. There are ones where the Document sits inside the **contentDocument** object whereas the video player iframe has its document object sitting inside **contentWindow** object.

I have had to write two functions to deal with them separately :

```
 Cypress.Commands.add('getIframeBody', (locator) => {
  cy.wait(1000)
  return cy.get(`iframe${locator}`)
  .its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty')
  .then(cy.wrap)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('getVideoPlayerBody', () => {
  return cy.get('[title="Video Player"]')
  .then(($iframe => {
    const $body = $iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body
    return cy.wrap($body)
  }))
})
```

I am looking for an explanation on why it is like this, is it just a development style  or there is actually a purpose / reason behind this occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but `contentWindow` & `contentDocument` are the `<iframe>` equivalent of `window` & `document`, as you might expect from the naming.

[Window - Web APIs - MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

> The Window interface represents a window containing a DOM document; the document property points to the DOM document loaded in that window

The `<iframe>` element has both properties `contentWindow` & `contentDocument` for convenience, but strictly speaking the hierarchy is as mentioned in the MDN link:

```js
iframe.contentWindow.contentDocument.body
```

The '0' in `its('0...` is just unwrapping the jQuery result to get the raw `<iframe>` element.

With regard to usage usage in the test, I found it depends on the complexity of the loading.

Sometimes you need to wait for the `contentWindow` first and sometimes `contentDocument` is required, depending on the scripts that perform the content loading.

You may have an initial static 'Content is loading`message, which changes refreshes the`contentWindow` when actual content is fetched via HTTP.

Ref: [HTMLIFrameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement)